# Question on combinatorics, partitions.

Tags: integer-partitions

Let $p$ ($n|$distinct odd parts) be the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct odd parts.  Prove that $p(n)$ is odd if and only if $p$($n|$distinct odd parts) is odd by using the theorem on self-conjugate partitions.

Ok, so we count the hooks in the Ferrers diagram, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but the result follows easily from the one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92191/identity-involving-partitions-of-even-and-odd-parts), which has both a combinatorial answer and one that uses generating functions.

Answer (score 1):

Partitions that aren't self-conjugate come in pairs, so $p(n)$ has the same parity as the number of self-conjugate partitions. But I assume that "the theorem on self-conjugate partitions" is the one that says the number of self-conjugate partitions is the number of partitions into distinct odd parts. So, $p(n)$ has the same parity as the number of partitions into distinct odd parts.