# Partition Generating Function (Truncation)

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

Let $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_nx^n$ be the partition generating function, and let $P^*(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p^*_nx^n$, where
$$p^*_n = \binom{\text{number of partitions of }n}{\text{into an even number of parts}} - \binom{\text{number of partitions of }n}{\text{into an odd number of parts}}.$$

Compute the truncation of $P(x)P^*(x)$ to degree $10$; that is, determine the polynomial consisting of all terms in the power series expansion of $P(x)P^*(x)$ with degree less than or equal to $10$.

---

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can you write $P(x)$ as a product? And $P^\ast(x)$?

Comment: I’ve not really thought about it, but it may be helpful to know that $(-1)^np_n^*$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into *distinct* odd parts; there are two proofs of this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92191/identity-involving-partitions-of-even-and-odd-parts).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott's answer over there almost contains what I was aiming at. So I recommend looking at that.